# Why was Subaru Konoe transferred into Kureha's class?

Tags: mayo-chiki

In episode 12, **Takanashi Punyuru** appeared as transferred student in Sakamachi Kureha's class. However, when she was Kanade's butler (**Subaru Konoe**), she was on same class with **Sakamachi Kinjirou**. Why was she transferred to Kureha's class instead of Kinjirou's?

Answer (score 1):

As I was reading manga of *Mayo Chiki*, I found the answer. I might have missed it while watching anime.

In **Volume 3 Chapter 18 - Bayside Baby**, when Kureha and and others met them at the beach, Kanade introduced Konoe as **Takanashi Punyuru**, a younger cousin of Konoe, and same grade as Kureha. This explains why Konoe as Takanashi Punyuru appeared as transfer student in Kureha's class.

Below is the part of chapter where Kanade says

> She's in the same grade as you, so you don't have to add the "-san"

In this context, **"she"** refers to Takanashi (Konoe) and **"you"** refers to Kureha.

[image]